# Should I keep my monitor away from direct sun light?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I do realize that this question has been answered at [Sun and or heat damage to back of monitor or computer](https://superuser.com/questions/376582/sun-and-or-heat-damage-to-back-of-monitor-or-computer) 
But it doesn't make it clear if it's OK to just leave the monitor(screen) exposed to the sun light in the morning (due to sunrise) for a couple hours(monitor is inside the room. + ~5 meters from windows, summer time.). I have an Asus (ASUS VX239H) WLED monitor, and there is no information about keeping the monitor away of direct sun light. Is it OK in the long run?

Comment: What latitude (big difference in UV equator vs. pole)?  Direct exposure or through single or double-pane window?  Back of the monitor or screen?  How many hours?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for your input. I added a few details. just to make my question complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given enough time, UV from sunlight can destroy just about anything. Monitors aren't designed to be UV safe, as they're not typically used outdoors, or in direct sunlight. If it's in direct sunlight for a couple of hours every day, it will eventually damage it. I would recommend at the very least covering it with a cloth or something when not in use.